# Issue with JSP AJAX jQuery fill table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I wrote a servlet to retrieve data from a MongoDB database and display it in a table in a JSP file:

The servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    MongoClient mongo = (MongoClient) request.getServletContext().getAttribute("MONGO_CLIENT");
    ArrayList <tt> tt = new ArrayList<tt>();
    DBO dao = new DB(mongo);
    tt = dao.getAll();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(tt, new TypeToken<List<tt>>() {}.getType());
    JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
    log.debug(jsonArray.toString());
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);

}
```

My JSPfile contains the JavaScript file (for the moment):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get('/ttSRV/webttServlet',function(responseJson) {
            if(responseJson!=null){
                $("#tttable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                var table1 = $("#tttable");
                $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) { 
                    var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td ></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
                    rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['owner']); 
                    rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['nom']); 
                    rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['date']); 
                    rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['reception']); 
                    rowNew.children().eq(4).text(value['ren']); 
                    rowNew.children().eq(5).text(value['status']);
                    rowNew.children().eq(6).text("<a class=\"btn btn-success\" href=\"#\"><i class=\"icon-zoom-in icon-white\"></i>Voir</a><a class=\"btn btn-danger\" href=\"#\"><i class=\"icon-trash icon-white\"></i>Supprimer</a>");
                    rowNew.appendTo(table1);
                });
            }
        });        
    });
</script>
```

It's working fine but my last row :

```
rowNew.children().eq(6).text
```

is containing a hyperlink to display or delete the item and is displayed as a String. How can I display it as a `<a>` hyperlink and not as a String ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing `rowNew.children().eq(6).text(` to `rowNew.children().eq(6).html(` ?

The .text function renders text only, while html renders Raw html.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#example1").text("<b>Hello world!</b>");  
});
```

The first example writes: `<b>Hello world!</b>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#example2").html("<b>Hello world!</b>");
});
```

The second example writes: **Hello world!**